# how to popout the image in wpf not only the height and width but also left and top?

Tags: wpf, image, scale

hi guyz i saw and tried the code using scaletransform from andrej blog on how to popout the image smoothly and it's nice. here's the code

```
<Window.Resources>
 <Storyboard x:Key="expandStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
        To="2" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
        To="2" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
</Storyboard>
<!-- This storyboard will make the image revert to its original size -->
<Storyboard x:Key="shrinkStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
        To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
        To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
</Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

and in grid area, something like this:

```
        <Image Name="image2" Source="C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\settings_256.png" Margin="23,44,372,221" HorizontalAlignment=" center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource expandStoryboard}" />
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource shrinkStoryboard}" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
```

so when im going to point my mouse in the image it will resize the height and the width of the image smoothly. but what i want to do also is if im going to do mouseover, i want my left and top of the image will change the position like decreasing the margin something like image1.margin(left-5,top-5). so it will pop the image out as width++ height++ left-- top--

anyone? thanks and God bless :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin.aspx):

```
<Image RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
       Name="image2" Source="C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\settings_256.png"
       Margin="23,44,372,221" HorizontalAlignment="center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource expandStoryboard}" />
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource shrinkStoryboard}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but which part should im going to put this image rendertransformorigin? sorry im just new with wpf...

Comment: i tried changing  <Image.RenderTransform><ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/></Image.RenderTransform> to <Image.RenderTransformOrigin><Point X="0.5" Y="0.5" />           </Image.RenderTransformOrigin> but it gives me an error "Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'RenderTransform.ScaleX'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties."

Comment: wow!!!!! thank you so much LPL... now i can put some animation to my button. God bless :)